# Cryptically Coping

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Tetchy that jafe just outputs one puzzle per week? Well, think twice! jafe's jamming quite quickly, seemingly superhumanly! However here's my mollification, another attempt. Hearty hopes thou takest enjoyment, erudition.

[image: Grid]

**ACROSS**
**1** "I'm a riot!," man rambled before lauding institution of marriage (11)
**7** Half-orc's maw (3)
**9** Country of Palau stripped of gold to support Niue extremists (5)
**10** Eats spicy tacos, salsa in Miami location (4,5)
**11** Slug of tequila lead to grounded stern after neglecting sag to port (9)
**12** Not a single time now (5)
**13** Push right into tapioca preparation after paring fruit (7)
**15** Trio, duet alternate in sophisticated affair (4)
**18** Turn in website address after losing almost all traffic (4)
**20** Visionary in verse, Gray enthralls me (7)
**23** A warehouse loses nothing? Good. (5)
**24** Swiss enamel sprayed to cover old surface with one that blends into surroundings (9)
**26** Wrestler grabs a left upper forearm and, reversing counter, ties top half in a knot (4,5)
**27** Precipitate reaction is pure, carbon-free (5)
**28** Casual sport, for short (3)
**29** Doctors strap idiots loosely (11)

**DOWN**
**1** Madame Curie finally extracted, bottled up noble gas and oxygen to create initial compound? (8)
**2** Hanging with kinetic art types (8)
**3** Less used to LED scattering in sub-light spectrum (5)
**4** Pick over pine nuts to make traditional barbecue (4-3)
**5** Member of exclusive club for daring diners tastes okapi tail (7)
**6** Grant of permission belies, at heart, disapproval (9)
**7** Knot of angry rebels quartering Amin at terminal (6)
**8** Exchange rand in trade for tala and pound (6)
**14** Dating a bit assumes that we have reserved time (9)
**16** Swimmers establish hiding places in the water (8)
**17** Beneficiaries of Sergeant Slaughter (8)
**19** Tone of rap, less intense after intro, picked up (7)
**20** Stormily march in father's way to demand payment for Greek dues (7)
**21** Filmmaker Howard's trailer compressed tenfold and edited (6)
**22** Feel poorly upon prescription injection? A nervous reaction. (6)
**25** Comet Hergenrother obscured the sky (5)

#### Solver Notes

There's nothing to the alliteration in the intro text. There's just only so many ways you can say "here's another cryptic with no theme", and I got bored. Maybe I should do a theme next time...

#### Text Version

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|1  |   |2  |   |3  |   |4  |   |5  |   |6  |███|7  |   |8  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|9  |   |   |   |   |███|10 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|11 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |███|12 |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   |███|   |███|███|███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|13 |   |   |   |14 |   |   |███|15 |   |   |   |███|███|███|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   |███|   |███|   |███|███|███|███|███|   |███|16 |███|17 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|███|███|███|18 |   |   |19 |███|20 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|21 |███|22 |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|███|███|   |███|   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|23 |   |   |   |   |███|24 |   |   |   |25 |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|26 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |███|27 |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|28 |   |   |███|29 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

Explanations:

ACROSS

> 1 MATRIMONIAL **IMARIOTMAN* + L(-auding)** "I'm a riot!," man rambled before lauding institution of marriage (11)
> 7 GOB **GOB(-lin)** Half-orc's maw (3)
> 9 NEPAL **PAL(-au) supporting N(-iu)E** Country of Palau stripped of gold to support Niue extremists (5)
> 10 EAST COAST **EATS* TACOS*** Eats spicy tacos, salsa in Miami location (4,5)
> 11 GASTROPOD **T(-equila)->(-grounde)D in (SAG TO PORT)*** Slug of tequila lead to grounded stern after neglecting sag to port (9)
> 12 NONCE **N + ONCE** Not a single time now (5)
> 13 APRICOT **R in TAPIOC(-a)*** Push right into tapioca preparation after paring fruit (7)
> 15 ROUT **tRiOdUeT** Trio, duet alternate in sophisticated affair (4)
> 18 FURL **URL after (-tra)F(-fic)** Turn in website address after losing almost all traffic (4)
> 20 DREAMER **DREAR containing ME** Visionary in verse, Gray enthralls me (7)
> 23 ADEPT **A DEP(-o)T** A warehouse loses nothing? Good. (5)
> 24 CHAMELEON **CH + ENAMEL* containing O** Swiss enamel sprayed to cover old surface with one that blends into surroundings (9)
> 26 HALF HITCH **HHH grabs (A L F(-orearm)) and (C TI(-es))<** Wrestler grabs a left upper forearm and, reversing counter, ties top half in a knot (4,5)
> 27 HASTE **(-c)HASTE** Precipitate reaction is pure, carbon-free (5)
> 28 LAX **ddef** Casual sport, for short (3)
> 29 PODIATRISTS **(STRAP IDIOTS)*** Doctors strap idiots loosely (11)

DOWN

> 1 MONOGRAM **MM(-e) containing (ARGON+O)<** Madame Curie finally extracted, bottled up noble gas and oxygen to create initial compound? (8)
> 2 TAPESTRY **ARTTYPES*** Hanging with kinetic art types (8)
> 3 IDLER **LED* in IR** Less used to LED scattering in sub-light spectrum (5)
> 4 OPEN-PIT **OPT containing PINE*** Pick over pine nuts to make traditional barbecue (4-3)
> 5 INSIDER **DINERS* containing (-okap)I** Member of exclusive club for daring diners tastes okapi tail (7)
> 6 LICENSURE **(-be)LI(-es) + CENSURE** Grant of permission belies, at heart, disapproval (9)
> 7 GRANNY **ANGRY* containing (-ami)N** Knot of angry rebels quartering Amin at terminal (6)
> 8 BATTER **BA[r->t]TER** Exchange rand in trade for tala and pound (6)
> 14 COURTSHIP **CHIP containing OURS containing T** Dating a bit assumes that we have reserved time (9)
> 16 IMMERSES **substring** Swimmers establish hiding places in the water (8)
> 17 GRANTEES **SERGEANT*** Beneficiaries of Sergeant Slaughter (8)
> 19 LOCATED **LOC + (-b)ATED** Tone of rap, less intense after intro, picked up (7)
> 20 DRACHMA **MARCH* in DA** Stormily march in father's way to demand payment for Greek dues (7)
> 21 WARHOL **HOWAR(d->L)*** Filmmaker Howard's trailer compressed tenfold and edited (6)
> 22 REFLEX **FEEL* in RX** Feel poorly upon prescription injection? A nervous reaction. (6)
> 25 ETHER **substring** Comet Hergenrother obscured the sky (5)

Credit where due:

> Thanks to Stiv for suggesting in comments explanations for two clues I hadn't figured out the wordplay for: 19d (where I had no idea at all) and 26a (where I had most of it but was missing one key piece).

Also worth noting:

> It turns out Jeremy intended CURL rather than FURL for 18a. I think they work about equally well.

Comment: Great job! I'll leave your two identified issues to see if others can puzzle them out. But for 18A, I meant rot13(PHEY = HEY + (-genssv)P), which I think works a little better, though I certainly see the logic of your answer.

Comment: Oh, interesting! I think both solutions are valid, for good or ill :-).

Comment: Re 18A, I think the part you're missing is that 'counter' = C (likely in acronyms like CCW for counter-clockwise) so you are *reversing* CTI (not just TI). Also 'Tone of rap' = [LOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_Loc) which might help fully resolve that wordplay...

Comment: "[That Medina's a monster, y'all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63ZIf2H9S0E)" When punking my kids, I should have claimed to play cowbell on this song...instead I used [Low Rider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsrqKE1iqqo)..

Comment: Ah, hadn't thought of "counterclockwise", good call. And of course I had never heard of Tone Loc. Will make appropriate edits.